# Openrefine convert number to date

Tags: openrefine

I am using Version 3.4.1 [437dc4d] of OpenRefine and a column that keeps numbers like 1986 which is a year. I am trying to convert them to year by clicking `Edit cells` -> `Common transform` -> `to date` , however I get `Text transform on 0 cells in column first_appeared: value.toDate()`  what do I have to do to convert them to date? I see that the error is `Error: Unable to parse as date`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. I created a new project from clipboard with two lines with the content 1986 and 1985. In OpenRefine I used the function convert to date successfully.

Comment: @magdmartin: From which data source did you load the data into OpenRefine?

Comment: I used `copy from clipboard`

Answer (score 0):

I used Open Refine 3.4.1 to reconstruct the situation.

***That's what I did***

1. Create Project, paste in two year values via clipboard into Open Refine evironment and press Next

- Result:
  [image: Result step 1]
  The data from clipboard were classified as line based text automatically.
  For this demo usecase it's fine. But datatype can be also different.

2. Press Create Project

- Result:
  [image: Result step 2]

3. Prepare edit cells for the column

- Result:
  [image: Result step 3]

4. Execute edit cells

- Result:
  [image: Result step 4]
  Open Refine was executing this function: value.toDate(). It was producing a Date format out of the string - that means: it has transformed the 4 digit origin into a date format.
  A valid date object contains more than 4 digits as years - that's the reason why Open Refine did that.